# How to pass parameters to ActiveModel serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm using [active model serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). I have a model event which has_many activities.

I want to return the event with the first n activities. I think I should pass the params n to the event serializer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Options passed in are available through the `@options` hash. So if you do:

```
respond_with @event, activity_count: 5
```

You can use `@options[:activity_count]` within the serializer.

Comment: As of AMS 0.9.0, this doesn't work. Since AMS has no documentation, no wiki, and no discussion boards, this seems to be a dead-end at this time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: On the AMS Github page. Ctrl+F "options ", it is under "render :json".

Comment: It's on 0.8 branch, not on master. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable We really need this. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/599

Comment: Safer to use 0.8 version if you can since it's recommended by the AMS team.  `we recommend that any new projects you start use the latest 0.8.x version of this gem. This version is the most widely used, and will most closely resemble the forthcoming release.`

Comment: `@options` did not seem to work for me, it turns out the hash changed to  `@instance_options` instead. That did it for me.

Comment: active_model_serializers (0.10.2) neither does work.

Answer (score 117):

In version `~> 0.10.0` you need to use `@instance_options`. Using @Jon Gold example from above:

```
# controller
def action
  render json: @model, option_name: value
end

# serializer
class ModelSerializer::ActiveModel::Serializer
  def some_method
    puts @instance_options[:option_name]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 47):

The `@options` hash was removed in `0.9`; looks like an equivalent method was [recently added](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/679) -

```
def action
  render json: @model, option_name: value
end

class ModelSerializer::ActiveModel::Serializer
  def some_method
    puts serialization_options[:option_name]
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the gem version 0.9 (updated it just to be sure) but both the options and serialization_options doesn't work. This is the error

undefined local variable or method `serialization_options'

Comment: ganeshran is right. `serialization_options` should work on 0.9 but it seems like using 0.8 and `@options` is the only way that works at the moment.

Answer (score 16):

As of `0.10` of [active model serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) you can pass arbitrary options via the `instance_options` variable as seen [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/passing_arbitrary_options.md).

```
# posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard
    render json: @post, user_id: 12
  end
end

# post_serializer.rb
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body
  def comments_by_me
    Comments.where(user_id: instance_options[:user_id], post_id: object.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `0.10` a Rails version?

Comment: Watch out - this method can be used only in the  eg `attributes` methods.
It did not show when i tried to check it in a `has_many` action.

Answer (score 14):

Using 0.9.3 you can use #serialization_options like so...

```
# app/serializers/paginated_form_serializer.rb
class PaginatedFormSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :rows, :total_count

  def rows
    object.map { |o| FormSerializer.new(o) }
  end

  def total_count
    serialization_options[:total_count]
  end
end

# app/controllers/api/forms_controller.rb
class Api::FormsController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    forms = Form.page(params[:page_index]).per(params[:page_size])
    render json: forms, serializer: PaginatedFormSerializer, total_count: Form.count, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

**serialization_options** works well with Active Model Serialization 0.9.3.

The options passed along with render command can be accessed in the serializer using their keys -> *serialization_options[:key]*

Answer (score -3):

simple way is just add activities method in the event serializer and return n number of activities. That is it.

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  has_many :activities

  def activities
    object.activities[0..9] # Select whatever you want
  end
end
```

Comment: Except you have hardcoded which activities are returned. The entire point of the 'options' hash is for the API to provide different options to the consumer of an endpoint.