# Pass options to ActiveModelSerializers 0.9.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Is there a way I can pass options to new version of AMS like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23347781/260138) shows?

Answer (score 2):

You can parse options `Hash` when creating a new instance of a serializer, but the only attribute it will use is the `:root` as you can see on `ActiveModel::Serializer` [source code](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L119):

```
def initialize(object, options = {})
  @object = object
  @root   = options[:root] || (self.class._root ? self.class.root_name : false)
end
```

You can override this method on you Serializer class and use the rest of the options as you wish:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :body

  def initialize(object, options = {})
    super(object, options)
    # Your custom code goes here
  end
end
```