# How to pass parameters to ActiveModel::ArraySerializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I need to have access to `current_user_id` from within ItemSerializer.
Is there a way to achieve it? I am fine even with a dirty hack :)

I know about existence of `serialization_options` hash (from [How to pass parameters to ActiveModel serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347587/how-to-pass-parameters-to-activemodel-serializer)
) but it works only with `render` command (if I am right) so it's possible to do:

```
def action
  render json: @model, option_name: value
end

class ModelSerializer::ActiveModel::Serializer
  def some_method
    puts serialization_options[:option_name]
  end
end
```

but in my case I use `ArraySerializer` to generate a json hash outside of `render` command like so:

```
positions_results = {}    
positions_results[swimlane_id][column_id] =
  ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@account.items,
                                   each_serializer: ItemSerializer,
                                   current_user_id: current_user.id) # <---- Does not work
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:

- Pass them through `serialization_options`, but as far as I know, and as you stated, you can only use it in a response from a controller:
- Pass them through `context` or `scope` as you stated, and it's pretty much the same:

  ```
  # same as with scope 
  ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@account.items, each_serializer: ItemSerializer, context: {current_user_id: 31337})

  # In serializer:
  class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :scope, :user_id

      def user_id
        context[:current_user_id]
      end
  end
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Basically the answer is here:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/510

```
ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
                            @account.items,
                            each_serializer: ItemSerializer,
                            scope: {current_user_id: 31337})
```

and then in `ItemSerializer`:

```
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :scope, :user_id

    def user_id
      # scope can be nil
      scope[:current_user_id]
    end
end
```

Hope it helps anyone :)