# Pass variable from Controller to Serializer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have this code in my Controller to get distance in meters from one location to another location:

```
range = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([lat,lng],[Model.location.lat,Model.location.lng])
rangeInMeters = range * 1000            
rangeRounded = rangeInMeters.round
rangeRounded = rangeRounded / 100 * 100
```

and I have this code in my serializer to give a nicer output for the json response like this:

```
class ModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :address, :range

  def range
  // something
  end
end
```

How to get rangeRounded be read by ModelSerializer so in json response it would be like this:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name A",
        "address": "Address A",
        "range": 500
    },
```

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956952/2545197

Comment: I've tried this, but it won't work, don't know what's wrong

Comment: Can you show some example how are you trying to pass it?

Comment: sure,
`attributes :id, :name, :address, :range
  # has_many :locations

  def range
    puts @instance_options[:rangeRounded]
  end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly your model has `location` which has `lat` and `lng`. And you want to access these fields in your serializer method.

You can access these fields using `object.`

[RailsCasts - Active Model Serializers episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

```
#controller
def action
    ...
    range = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([lat,lng],[Model.location.lat,Model.location.lng])
    range_in_meters = range * 1000            
    range_rounded = range_in_meters.round
    range_rounded = range_rounded / 100 * 100
    ...

    render json: @model, serializer: ModelSerializer, range_rounded: range_rounded
end


#serializer
class ModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :address, :range
    #point assosiations here (same as in model)

    def range
        puts @instance_options[:range_rounded]
    end
end
```

Comment: could you please elaborate? I'm still learning about this serializer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Provide your controller code where you want to respond with serialized `model`, and model

Comment: the `rangeRounded` variable that needed to be serialized from the post above.

Comment: this comes up, the same as I had before, Sir
`undefined local variable or method rangeRounded`

Comment: Made some chages. Try it again

Comment: it's even come up with weird error `undefined method id`, even the attributes :id I have explicitly mentioned.

Comment: It will be much easier to figure out if you provide model and controller code

Comment: Hello, sir, I get resolved with this code
render json: models, scope: {
            'range': @rangeRounded
        }